# Excel if statement dynamic

Tags: excel, if-statement

with the current cell here:

[image]

Is there a way to make an if statement that takes the price in b if there is an x in c ?

i tried with

```
=IF(b2="x, a2+") etc.
```

But that wouldn't work, and that would make it quite a bit of manual work, not very dynamic.

Is there a way to just mark cells in c so i can add more cells and the formula would continue to work.

Comment: "that wouldn't work", what's the behaviour?

Comment: i get an error in excel. "there are problems with this formula etc."

Comment: `quite a bit of manual work, not very dynamic` - unless you specifically use absolute references, the formula will change to the next row when you drag it down. Unless you are talking about a formula for the Total cell (which is not clear from your question), in which case you want `SUMIF`.

Comment: `SUMIF()` ? Needs a bit more explanation.

Comment: Syntax error, so fix it. Read the documentation to know how does the `IF` command work and use ti properly.

Comment: I did try reading documentation on it, but most was about grades and stuff, haven't been able to turn it what i need.

Comment: Remember that just use others' code without understanding what it does won't help you to improve your programming ability.

Comment: @user202729 i am fully aware, and i belive it indeed will help me understand its meaning, when i go back to read more.

Comment: @user202729, i got it now, IF( logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false ) and because my excel is in danish i change IF to hvis, then it works. It did indeed help me understand, by getting the answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this IF statement in D1:

```
=IF(C1="x";A1;"")
```

Then, you can copy the contents of cell D1 down to the other cells in the same column or use the mouse to drag the right-bottom corner of cell D1

Comment: it says #name? and "unknown name"

Comment: If your spreadsheet is exactly as above, putting '=IF(C1="x";A1;"")' into cell D1 should work. It will be empty until you fill C1 with 'x'

Comment: I think i got the error because my excel is in danish, because if i use this =HVIS(C3="x";A3;0) then it works. So your answer was correct indeed ^^

Comment: Ah... Strange choice by Microsoft to translate function names.

Comment: yearh, i thought so too.

Comment: Function names are translated for many languages - one of the issues I have with my students...